# Can I deserialize proto to object type

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

It is known that protobuf-net is not created for dynamic procession of data, but   if serialized object to proto file, can I deserialize it again to object and use it as a dynamic.

As an example:

```
object p = new
{
    Value = "Test"
};

//Saving object to file works perfectly
using (var file = File.Create("test.bin"))
{
    Serializer.Serialize(file, p);
}

//But this doesn't
using (var file = File.OpenRead("test.bin"))
{
    dynamic data = Serializer.Deserialize<object>(file);
    Console.WriteLine(data.Id);
}
```

Is there any way to deserialize proto to object type?

Answer (score 2):

Right now: no. Partly because it hasn't been necessary, and partly because .proto is ambiguous without additional information. That information is usually provided either by a .proto schema file, or (in the case of protobuf-net) via code attributes. Without that context there are a lot of values that cannot be correctly interpreted.

Adding true `dynamic` support is on the wish list of things that may warrant investigation, but as per the above: if you don't have a `Type`, you'll need to provide a message descriptor instead (this could be compiled as .proto, or as text, hypothetically - since protobuf-net has a fully managed schema parser).

If you do have a `Type` but just done have a `<T>`, then note that protobuf-net also has a full non-generic API that accepts `Type` as an input.

Comment: So, to cast proto to object type i need to provide schema for deserialization. Am i right?

Comment: @Dakito no, right now only `Type`-based deserialization exists - unless you deserialize to `ExtensibleObject` and do it all manually. The ability to pass in a message descriptor (a `message` definition in .proto terms) is a future feature I'd *like* to add, but which hasn't seen any significant demand